# Building Carla 9.11 on Windows. Error LNK2038 on make PythonAPI

Tags: python, windows, cmake, build, carla

Sorry for addressing this question here but I didn't find anything on github. I spent a lot of time trying to build Carla simulator and I've got this error on make PythonAPI

xerces-c_3.lib(DOMStringPool.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in libcarla.obj
xerces-c_3.lib(XPathSymbols.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in libcarla.obj
xerces-c_3.lib(XSTypeDefinition.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in libcarla.obj
xerces-c_3.lib(XMLGrammarDescription.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in libcarla.obj
xerces-c_3.lib(FieldValueMap.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in libcarla.obj
Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\source/libcarla\libcarla.cp37-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\source/libcarla\libcarla.cp37-win_amd64.exp
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\carla\libcarla.cp37-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1319: 523 mismatches detected
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe' failed with exit status 1319

Windows 10
Carla version 9.11
Python version 3.7.4

If you have any ideas they are welcome, and sorry for the quesion again. Thank you!